# Fancybox Video continues to play when closed

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Just implemented Fancybox to pop up on the page load — however, when the user clicks out of the fancybox back to the website, the song will begin to play again. Any ideas on what could cause this?

LINK: [People Like Us Website](http://peoplelikeusmusic.com)

```
<!-- FANCYBOX POPUP -->
<a class="popupLink" href="#popup"></a>
<div id="popup">
     <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qw7k_erTgow?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<!-- .popup -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".popupLink").fancybox();                    

     window.setTimeout('$(".popupLink").trigger("click")', 100);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.more").click(function() {
$.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
             'wmode'           : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'  : 'true'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid potential conflicts you should load a single version of jQuery (you have two : v1.4 and v1.7)

Second, same as jQuery you are loading two different versions of fancybox (you have : v1.3.4 and v2.0.3)

Third, personally I don't think is a good idea to have an `inline` iframe for videos since you don't really have control of what happens inside the `iframe`. Additionally, it might add an overhead to your page load and other potential issues like the one you are experiencing.

The good news is that you can open your video "on-demand" inside fancybox, in other words, only when you need it and not there hidden in your page and playing in the background ... so I would suggest these changes to your code :

*html*

```
<a class="popupLink" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Qw7k_erTgow?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque"></a>
```

... and delete the inline iframe `<div id="popup"><iframe ...></div>`

*js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".popupLink").fancybox({
    "padding": 1,
    "type": "iframe",
    "width": 853,
    "height": 480
  });
  window.setTimeout('$(".popupLink").trigger("click")', 100);
}); // ready
```